# Kendo Grid Inline Incell Editing Currency Format changes in Editing Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formatting, kendo-grid, decimal, culture

I'm using a Kendo Grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kosten>()
    .Name("gridKosten")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Costs);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("gridError"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Kosten_Create", "FahnenSettings"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Kosten_RetrieveAll", "FahnenSettings"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Kosten_Update", "FahnenSettings"))
    )
    .Editable(editable => editable
        .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
)
```

Also I set the culture to German.

```
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/messages/kendo.messages.de-DE.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            kendo.culture("de-DE");
        })
    </script>
```

Everything works fine. In my column "Costs" the displayed value is like "1.245,21 €". But when I'm activating the "Edit" function, the value in the input has changed to "1245.21" (check the separator). Do I change the value now to something like "1245.20", the value will become "124.520,00 €".

So if I want to have the correct value, I always have to change back the separator "." to "," manually. My culture is set to German, it shows the german value and it interprete the german spelling with comma correctly after editing. But in the moment I open the inline editing mode, the separator is changing to us format with a dot.

How can I avoid that? Someone has an idea?

The column property is set in the model like

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Costs { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem.

I solved it by including the "~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates" folder. I removed it at the beginning from my solution because I thought these Views were only examples and didn't thought they were actually used. The grid wanted to use the missing "Currency.cshtml" in it.